# Java: Encrypt JPG File inside .jar package

Tags: java, encryption, jar

When bundling some images inside a .jar Package (Java+Swing), what is the best way to protect the JPG files inside to prevent users from accessing the package and copying aforesaid images for their own?

Comment: Do the images get displayed in the application?  If so, what is to stop the end user from taking a screen-shot?  Bye-bye picture!  If someone delivered an app. to me that tried to restrict my access to resources, I'd whip up some Robot to go through every page/image then take a screenshot.  Save them to disk.  Done.

Answer (score 2):

You can encrypt them before including them in the JAR, then unencrypt right before displaying (or otherwise using) in your app. The trivial implementation of this would require you to bundle the private key with your app, which basically negates the encryption if the 'user' is determined enough. Alternatively, you could download the key off a hosted site when your app launches. Not foolproof and it will drag the performance of your application down.

Or you could split the images into random frames and combine them right before display. Basically obsfucate the data.

There's a million ways to be honest, haha, but really, none of them are foolproof and are bound to be more trouble than its worth. After all you are going to display the image eventually correct? At which point the 'user' can just do a screen grab.

If you are that concerned with your copyrights then I suggest you watermark your pictures, so you have legal recourse if you discover someone using them.

Answer (score 0):

You could write some basic code for symmetric encryption/decryption of your images. This would prevent an amateur user from stealing your images, but a hacker will be able to decrypt them all in some hours.
For symmetric encryption example see http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Security/Basicsymmetricencryptionexample.htm

Answer (score -1):

You can get the byte representation of the image, and save it with another file extension, or you can encrypt it with the javax.crypto package, but I don't think it's necesary.

Comment: How does changing the file extension have any effect?

Comment: you can change it to a .something extension that the users can't open, think of it a normal serialization, you save the Image object into a binary file, in this case the bytes that compose the file are in the same order than the "real" image, besides, I don't think it's fun to try and mess with the image file structure by encrypting it...

Comment: A typical image viewer can open images no matter what extension you give them. They use magic bytes to see a file is a jpg image. For example when I open a renamed jpg file with irfanview it tells me it's a jpg with a wrong file extension and offers to rename it.

Comment: *"you can encrypt it with the javax.crypto package"*  Sure you can. But if the code can decrypt it, the user can reverse engineer the code, then decrypt it themselves.  The first idea was nonsense, and the 2nd would be ineffectual.  -1

Comment: You wouldn't need to encrypt anything. You could store the bytes backwards in a file, and then when read them back in the correct order when diplaying the image. I think people will take a screenshot rather than look inside the jar anyway..